# Regex code explanation

Tags: .net, regex

Can someone tell me what this line of code means, I know that it looks for regular expressions but i dont understand the bit at the end.

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(?<=<Last>).*(?=</Last>)");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Five questions with no selected answers?  Selecting an answer to some of your questions will likely help your chances at getting an answer here.

Comment: Why is this question tagged as SQL?

Comment: Judging from the identifiers in the code, it looks like you are targeting .NET and not SQL. That said, this line of code will not compile in any .NET language I know of…

Comment: @Jorn, this looks like C# to me.  Should compile

Comment: @Abe: What should it compile to? `Regex` is a class name, but in this code it is called like a method. My guess would be, that Tweedy wants to call a constructor on the `Regex` class. In that case C# requires the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(?<=<Last>)` is a look behind assertion. that means it matches `.*` only if there is a `<Last>` in front

`(?=</Last>)` is a look ahead assertion. ensures that there is a `<\Last>` following on `.*`

More information about regex in .net can be found [here on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Annotation, the provided example isn't a complete line of code ([See Class Regex on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=VS.80%29.aspx))

This should be a part of something like this:

```
Regex MyRegex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(?<=<Last>).*(?=</Last>)");
```

that creates a new Regex object.

Another possibility is to use regexes without creating regex objects, would look like this with the static method `isMatch`:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(StringToSearchIn, "(?<=<Last>).*(?=</Last>)")
```

This returns true or false.

Comment: @razlebe I added more information, hopefully now also unexperienced readers can benefit from this question and answer.

Answer (score 2):

As noted before, the pattern `(?<=<Last>).*(?=</Last>)` matches the longest string of text preceded by `<Last>` and followed by `</Last>`, expressed with the positive [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Note however, that due to the [greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), this matched string itself can also contain `<Last>` and/or `</Last>`…

Answer (score 1):

It's basically looking for the `<Last>` tags in some xml document including its contents.

?<= is a look behind assertion.  See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for a thorough explanation.